# Loop through column of tableview and get cell data

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I have a `TableView` with two Columns (let's call them A and B). I like to loop through column A and print their values to console. My code doesn't seem to work the way I want it to....

```java
for (int i : myTable.getItems().size()) {
      System.out.print(columnA.getCellData(i));
}
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Will you let me know how is it working and how would you like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost had it! But I don't think that `for` loop is valid - it expects an Array not an int.

```
 for (Object o : myTable.getItems()) {
        System.err.println(columnA.getCellData(o));
 }
```

Or if you are using Java 8, this is a shorter way:

```
myTable.getItems().stream().forEach((o)
            -> System.err.println(columnA.getCellData(o)));
```

This works for me.
If it doesn't just comment and I'll see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the code and found a small correction - the type of the item for getCellData() must be String not object. For the first example, this would result in:

```
for (String[] o : myTable.getItems()) {
  System.err.println(columnA.getCellData(o));
}
```

Comment: No. getItems() - The underlying data model for the TableView. Note that it has a generic type that must match the type of the TableView itself.